# How to set up a connection with Kerberos in Golang app?

Tags: docker, go, active-directory, kerberos

I have task to create `SSO` (single sign-on) in `Golang` application with the help of `Kerberos` and `Active Directory`. In other words, if an employee of the company makes a request for a specific URL, the service must return information about him.

I decided to use [gokrb5](https://github.com/jcmturner/gokrb5) library.

What I have done so far:

1) `SPN` name for the service was created in Active Directory.

2) `krb5.keytab` file for the service was created.

3) Active Directory and Kerberos server located on remote Windows server.

4) Golang application would be in Linux Docker container.

5) I install `Kerberos` client to Docker container.

6) I put `krb5.keytab` file to `etc` folder of Docker container.

7) Kerberos Realm: EXAMPLE.LOCAL.

8)  hostname for the KDC Server: CS001, CS002, CS003

What the configuration file `krb5.conf` for Kerberos client should look like? How in Golang application I can correctly send token to Kerberos?

Comment: Hi Nurzhan, did you figure it out? Care to share the answer / example, please?